"Shrinking" matrix to reduce memory usage and accelerate the solution of system of linear equations
Given a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, is there a method to obtain, say some decomposition into >1 rectangular matrices, or some special $n\times n$ matrix which can be stored using less memory but when used in iterative solving methods (like Jacobi) will give a solution close to using $A$?
Obviously, it implies that the computations probably will happen faster as well. So a way to trade precision for memory and speed.
For example, Singular Value Decomposition fits that description, i tried it and it seems to work in my case (i tested on diagonally dominant matrix), but not as good as i would like. Is there something else like this? Is this even worth looking into or for some algebraic reason there can't be any way to get good results with that?
I know this is kind of a broad and not very well-defined question, sorry. Googling it just didn't give me anything (even the SVD idea):)

Low-rank approximation is probably what you are looking for.  Picking the norm/cost function may require significant understanding of what features you wish to preserve well.

Thank you very much, i happen to overlook this somehow
